# Python how to print 1D list as 2D

Tags: python-3.x

I want to print a list [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] as

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Here is my code

```
for i,j in enumerate(list):
     if i  is not 0 and i % 3==0:
         print()
     else:
         print(j,end=" ")
```

My result is

```
1 2 3
5 6
8 9
```

Can someone help explain why this happen and give me some advise?

Comment: You are not printing anything when i%3 == 0, move the else condition and print j irrespective of the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should print the list item `j` unconditionally instead of doing it only when you are not printing a newline:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for i,j in enumerate(l):
     if i  is not 0 and i % 3==0:
         print()
     print(j,end=" ")
```

Comment: `i != 0` integers are not singletons. Better yet, just `i and not i % 3`

Comment: @MadPhysicist `i is not 0` actually works because integers are immutable and would always have the same `id` as an integer variable of the same value.

Comment: `i is not 0` is not the same as `i !=0`. Here you mean to use  `i !=0`and not the former

Comment: @Onyambu They are not the same but for integer variables they do have the same effect.

Comment: @blhsing. That is not true. Immutability has very little to do with it. You can construct two integer objects with the same value but different IDs. The caching optimization for small numbers that you are probably referring to is an implementation detail and may not always have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
tgt=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
n=3
print('\n'.join([' '.join(map(str, sl)) for sl in [tgt[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(tgt),n)]]))
```

Prints:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```